# Manage what users can add to your app

Tags: ios

In my app project, people can take a picture, and the picture will be shown in a custom annotationview, from the user location. What Im afraid of is - how can i reject an add, if the added picture is inappropriate?
Can I accept the added picture, before its getting released in the app?

Comment: First thing if you are thinking about user image then you can use any library for face detection or eye detection. Second case: If you think Apple will reject your app the answer is NO. Apple would not reject.

Comment: But what if the user should be adding images of buildings? Can I make a detection for that?

Comment: Yes.. you can that. If there is no face/eye then you can show alert.

Answer (score 0):

So when the user takes a picture, it's sent to a web service somewhere, yes? So when the web service receives a new picture you'll have to add it to a queue for moderation. Then you'll have to provide a way (a web page perhaps) for your moderator to review images in the moderation queue and either release or reject them.

Comment: Could be cool if possible. Do you know a web service, where it is possible?

Comment: Typically when someone writes an app, they write their own web service to support it. If your app doesn't have an associated web service, then do the pictures just remain on the device? If that's the case, why does it matter if the added pictures are appropriate or not?